# Is there any way to prioritize the order of controllers/directives being loaded in page in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a problem with controller that is being loaded before it has been getting from other directive an id he should have in order to load himself.

How can I organize the order of loading component in page?
Is there a way to tell controller or directive to load only if he got something in his scope?

Think about a parameter directiveA create and directiveB need that parameter in order to being load. How to prioritize the order so directiveA is createad or loaded before directiveB?

Comment: Is the `directiveA` and `directiveB` has a parent-child relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the require attribute:  [See the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate)

```
function SomeDirective () {
  return {
    ...
    require: '^SomeOtherController'
  }
}
```